# Expense checker (javascript program)

Tags: javascript

i need to make an expense checker, and this is the requirement in javascript:
In the div with the verdict id displays the message You spent too much! if the value of the expenses exceeds 20% of Jon's total income. Otherwise you will see the message Your expenses are in the parameters.

This is html code:

```
<div>
    <div>Valoare alocatie: <input id="revenue"></div>
    <div>Cheltuieli totale : <input id="expenses"></div>
    <button id="check-button">Verifică</button>
    <div id="verdict"></div>
</div>
```

how can i solve the problem ? i tried this:

```
let revenue=document.getElementById('revenue');
let expenses=document.getElementById('expenses');
let btn=document.getElementById('check-button');
let verdict=document.getElementById('verdict');
```

Comment: You tried importing variables and expected it to work?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
if(expenses > (20/100 * revenue)){
    verdict.innerText += 'You spent too much!';
} else {
    verdict.innerText += 'Your expenses are in the parameters';
}
```

Basically what it does is checks if the expenses are more than 20%(which can also be represented as 20/100) of revenue (* revenue) and prints out accordingly.